# Trying to write a Junit test, but it's failing

Tags: java, junit, junit4

Here is my code:

**Concatenate.java**

```
package concatenate;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Concatenate {
    private static String firstWord;
    private static String secondWord;

    public Concatenate(String firstWord, String secondWord) {
        Concatenate.firstWord = firstWord;
        Concatenate.secondWord = secondWord;
    }

    public String getFirst() {
        return firstWord;
    }

    public String getSecond() {
        return secondWord;
    }

    public static Concatenate something() {
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter first word");
        firstWord = myObj.nextLine();
//        Scanner newObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter second word");
        secondWord = myObj.nextLine();
        return new Concatenate(firstWord, secondWord);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Concatenate result = something();
        System.out.println(result.getFirst() + " " + result.getSecond());
    }

}
```

**ConcatenateTest.java**

```
package concatenate;

import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class ConcatenateTest {

    public ConcatenateTest() {
    }

    @Test
    public void testMain() {
        String firstWord = "Hello";
        String secondWord = "world";
        String expectedResult = "Hello world";
        Concatenate testResult = new Concatenate(firstWord, secondWord);
        assertEquals(expectedResult, testResult);
        assertEquals(1, 1);
    }
}
```

But when I run the test, it fails, and I get...

> Expected <hello world> but was concatenate.Concatenate@[alphanumeric string]

Any pointers please?

BTW, I tried to copy all this over to Eclipse, but it threw a whole bunch of additional errors. If anyone could tell me why that would also be great. https://i.stack.imgur.com/koFKk.jpg

TIA

Comment: Your screenshot shows you have set up your Eclipse-project to use JUnit 5.
But in your Java code you try to import the classes from
where they are in JUnit 4 (e.g. `import org.junit.Test;`).

Comment: @Thomas Fritsch - ah, that explains that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are comparing String with Concatenate object. So it won't match.

Better to create a concat method in the Concatenate class and assert the the output of the method

```
public String concat() {
    return firstWord + " " + secondWord;}
```

and compare

> assertEquals(expectedResult, testResult.concat());

Hope this clarifies your question

Comment: ah, great, that seems to have done the trick. Thanks ever so much!

Answer (score 0):

The test fails because expectedResult is a String and testResult is an instance of Concatenate. They are not equal.

```
"Hello world".equals(testResult) == false
```

Comment: I understand that, thanks, but what's the solution then please? Because when I try to make my Concatenate function return a String I get the error missing return statement, and when I try to make it void I get "'(' expected". I tried 'String testResult' too but that throws a type error.

Comment: When you create a method with the name of the class, it becomes the constructor. Constructors do not have return types, they construct an object of the class. You never actually write code that concatenates two strings here.

Comment: @Dejke - so is it wrong to use a constructor then? "You never actually write code that concatenates two strings here." - that's what `(result.getFirst() + " " + result.getSecond())` is supposed to do. It does show the concatenated text in the output.

Answer (score -1):

"I understand that, thanks, but what's the solution then please? Because when I try to make my Concatenate function return a String I get the error missing return statement"

Are you talking about your constructor? If yes It can't have a return.
You can override equals method then change your test

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    
    return firstWord +" "+secondWord;
}


assertEquals(expectedResult, testResult.toString());
```